# Checking the strength of a password using regexes

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, regex, validation

I'm a beginner in Python and I made a password checker. I'm following these rules:

- I have to use regex
- password must be at least 8 characters
- must have at least one lower case character
- must have at least one upper case character
- must have at least one special character
- must have at least one number

I also wanted to display a message letting the user know what conditions weren't met.

I'm a bit concerned by the succession of `if`s.

```
#strong password checks
import re

#ask the user for the password to check
pwtocheck = input('please enter the password to be checked:')

#Error message to be
Err_mess = ''

#first regex : at least one lower case characters
pw_lc = re.compile(r'([a-z]+)')

#second regex : at least one upper case characters
pw_uc = re.compile(r'([A-Z]+)')

#third regex: at least one special character
pw_sc = re.compile(r'([\-_\?!@#$%^&\*]+)')

#fourth regex : password must have at least one number
pw_d = re.compile(r'([0-9])+')

#create a list to be given to all() to evaluate if all conditions are met or not
cond_pw = [len(pwtocheck) > 8, pw_lc.search(pwtocheck), pw_uc.search(pwtocheck), pw_sc.search(pwtocheck), pw_d.search(pwtocheck)]


#building an error message
#is the password at least 8 characters
if len(pwtocheck) < 8:
    Err_mess = Err_mess + 'password is too short\n'

#first regex is none
if pw_lc.search(pwtocheck) is None:
    Err_mess = Err_mess + 'password needs at least one lower case character\n'

#second regex is None
if pw_uc.search(pwtocheck) is None:
    Err_mess = Err_mess + 'password needs at least one upper case character\n'


#third regex is None
if pw_sc.search(pwtocheck) is None:
    Err_mess = Err_mess + 'password needs at least one special character\n'


#fourth regex is none
if pw_d.search(pwtocheck) is None:
    Err_mess = Err_mess + 'password needs at least one number\n'


if all (cond_pw) is True: 
    print('password is ok')
else:
    print(Err_mess)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Concept

Current security research recommends [eliminating character composition requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/password-guidance/). It's more important to blacklist common weak passwords. Also, [passphrases](https://protonmail.com/blog/protonmail-com-blog-password-vs-passphrase/) are a good alternative to passwords. For the purposes of this code review, though, I'll play along with your original premise.

### Style

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official Python style guide, recommends `lower_case_with_underscores` for variable names. `Err_mess` violates that guideline for no good reason.

### Regexes

You don't need the capturing parentheses, if you're not going to do anything with the capture groups. You also don't need the `+` modifiers, since the requirement is for just one character of each class.

Within a character class (inside square brackets), most characters lose their special meanings. You don't need to escape `?` and `*` with backslashes.

### Design

You're performing each check twice: once to check the password validity, and a second time to gather all of the failure reasons.

This code suffers from the fact that the rules are encoded in multiple places:

- the regular expressions (and their variable names)
- the comments
- the `if` statements (note especially the length check, which breaks the pattern)
- the error message strings

It would be better to treat all of the rules as data, uniformly, and have a single statement that performs all of the checks.

```
import re

pw_to_check = input('please enter the password to be checked:')

rules = [
    ('password is too short', r'.{8}'),
    ('password needs at least one lower case character', r'[a-z]'),
    ('password needs at least one upper case character', r'[A-Z]'),
    ('password needs at least one special character', r'[-_?!@#$%^&*]'),
    ('password needs at least one number', r'[0-9]'),
]

err_msg = '\n'.join(
    req
    for req, regex in rules
    if not re.search(regex, pw_to_check)
)

print(err_msg or 'password is ok')
```

Answer (score 1):

> #### Your code looks great!

I'm guessing that the expression you wish to design, in a final/combined form, would somewhat look like,

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[?!@#$%^&*_-])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9?!@#$%^&*_-]{8}$
```

for instance, which of-course can be likely simplified.

---

Here, we are using four positive lookaheads to check for those `at least` conditions, anywhere in the 8 chars.

We probably don't want to escape some metachars inside the character class `[]`,  usually we would include `-` at the end, which is used as a **range** inside a char class such as `a-z`, `A-Z` and `A-z`.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VGvnUa/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/VGvnUa/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[?!@#$%^&*_-])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9?!@#$%^&*_-]{8}$"

test_str = """
aB&9aaaa
aB&9aaaaa
aB&9aaa
aB&9xy8a
"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE))
```

#### Output

```
['aB&9aaaa', 'aB&9xy8a']
```

#### Test with `re.finditer`

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[?!@#$%^&*_-])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9?!@#$%^&*_-]{8}$"

test_str = """
aB&9aaaa
aB&9aaaaa
aB&9aaa
aB&9xy8a
"""

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Output

```
Match 1 was found at 1-9: aB&9aaaa
Match 2 was found at 28-36: aB&9xy8a
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Reference

[Regex for password must contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a)

Comment: Using four separate regular expressions keeps the code as readable as possible. Reading your combined regular expression is much more difficult.